# circle background not able to put around the icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                          <h3>Home</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>Document Missing
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                        <li>
                            <h3>Documents Submitted
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Urgent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Overdues</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Recurring</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

I have created a collapsible side navbar using jquery. Only problem I'm facing is that a circle background should be there on the plus and minus icon which I'm not able to implement. I have tried using using css but the alignment is not proper.
I have uploaded a piece of snippet. So can one please help me on this. the background should be displayed like in the picture below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this style to provide a rounded background

```
#vertical-menu h3 span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: border-radius: 50%; is used to make a structure in round shape...

if you provide height and width equally, then the structure will be rounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Check the following code and output. I have added display:flex,and align-items to center ,set a background to white and have given some radius for white circle background. And also I have used display:flex and align: center to h3 so that all content would come in center in a same row.

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                          <h3>Home</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>Document Missing
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                        <li>
                            <h3>Documents Submitted
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Urgent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Overdues</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Recurring</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background` and `border-radius` for this. Check updated snippet below..

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}

#vertical-menu h3 span {
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
  <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <h3>Home</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
          <h3>Document Missing
              <span class="plus">+</span>
          </h3>

          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Reports</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Search</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Graphs</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Settings</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
      <li>
          <h3>Documents Submitted
              <span class="plus">+</span>
          </h3>

          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Urgent</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Overdues</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Recurring</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Settings</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #003040;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
    margin: 10px 0;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                          <h3>Home</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>Document Missing
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                        <li>
                            <h3>Documents Submitted
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Urgent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Overdues</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Recurring</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a styling for the span to display the white circle and display the text `+` and  `-` in the span.

[image]

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 6px 0px;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">


                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                          <h3>Home</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>Document Missing
                                <span class="plus">  + </span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                        <li>
                            <h3>Documents Submitted
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Urgent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Overdues</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Recurring</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Comment: why not? I think it fulfills his requirements

Answer (score 0):

Use `background` and `border-radius` for the `span` tag. Please check the below snippet

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
  //slide up all the link lists
  $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
  $('.plus',this).html('+');
  //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
  if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
      //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
      $('.plus').html('+');
      $('.plus',this).html('-');
  }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
  background: #004050;
  width: 100%;
/* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
  color: white;
  /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
#vertical-menu h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
  background: #003040;
  background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
#vertical-menu h3:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
#vertical-menu h3 span {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: right;
  color: #111;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}

/*list items*/
#vertical-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
#vertical-menu ul ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 27px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
#vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #003545;
  /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#vertical-menu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <h3>Home</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Document Missing
            <span class="plus">+</span>
        </h3>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Search</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Graphs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
    <li>
        <h3>Documents Submitted
            <span class="plus">+</span>
        </h3>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Urgent</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overdues</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Recurring</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working codepen solution
Just add background color and all css in :after pseudo code in span:after and it is working fine 
[https://codepen.io/ruchitaghodasara/pen/oMpwdj][1]

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/ruchitaghodasara/pen/oMpwdj
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting background to Span tag worked for me:
here are the property i applied to span tag

- width: 23px;
- background-color: white;
- text-align: center;
- border-radius: 38px;
- height: 23px;
- margin-top: 5px;
- line-height: 1.3;

you can alter these property according to your will

```js
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        //$(this).remove("span").append('<span class="minus">-</span>');
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

```css
#vertical-menu {
    background: #004050;
    width: 100%;
   /* margin: 100px auto 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);*/
}
/*heading styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
 #vertical-menu h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
 #vertical-menu h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    color:#111;
}

/*list items*/
 #vertical-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    /*border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;*/
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
 #vertical-menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#vertical-menu li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
.plus
{
      width: 23px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 38px;
    height: 23px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                          <h3>Home</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>Document Missing
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graphs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- we will keep this LI open by default -->
                        <li>
                            <h3>Documents Submitted
                                <span class="plus">+</span>
                            </h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Today's tasks</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Urgent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Overdues</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Recurring</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```